# Is the controller ok? Error parsing one template meanwhile the others work fine

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm working on an exercise that simulates a store but when printing on screen the option to add products doesn't work. Print a whitelabel error:

> Whitelabel Error Page
>   This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>   Sat Mar 30 17:09:05 CET 2019
>   There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
>   An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/producto.html]")

I tried to improve the references in the model and changed the name to some parameters but the same error kept coming up.

This is the controller.

```
@Controller
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    ProductService productService;

    @GetMapping (value = "/addProduct")
    public String addProduct (Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("producto", new Product ());
        return "producto";

    }

    @GetMapping (value = "/deleteProduct")
    public String deleteProduct (Model model, @RequestParam Integer idProduct) {
        productService.deleteProduct(idProduct);
        return "redirect:/list-productos";

    }

    @GetMapping (value = "/updateProduct")
    public String updateProduct (Model model, @RequestParam Integer idProduct) {
        Product producto = productService.getProductById(idProduct);
        model.addAttribute("producto", producto);
        return "producto";

    }

    @PostMapping (value = "/addProduct")
    public String addProduct (Model model, String nombre, String descripcion, String marca, float precio) {
        productService.addProduct(nombre, descripcion, marca, precio);
        return "redirect:/list-productos";

    }

    @PostMapping (value = "/updateProduct")
    public String updateProduct (Model model, Product producto) {
        productService.updateProduct(producto);
        return "redirect:/list-productos";

    }


}
```

This is the service.

```
public interface ProductService {

    List<Product> getAll();

    Product getProductById(Integer idProduct);

    void addProduct(String nombre, String descripcion, String marca, float precio);

    void addProduct(Product product);

    void updateProduct(Product product);

    void deleteProduct(Integer idProduct);
}
```

This is the implementation.

```
@Service
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {

    @Autowired
    ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Product> getAll() {
        return productRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void addProduct(String nombre, String descripcion, String marca, float precio) {
        Product producto = new Product(nombre, descripcion, marca, precio);
        productRepository.save(producto);

    }

    @Override
    public void addProduct(Product product) {
        productRepository.save(product);

    }

    @Override
    public void updateProduct(Product product) {
        productRepository.save(product);

    }

    @Override
    public void deleteProduct(Integer idProduct) {
        Optional<Product> producto = productRepository.findById(idProduct);
        if (producto.isPresent()) {
            productRepository.deleteById(idProduct);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Product getProductById(Integer id) {     
        return productRepository.getOne(id);
    }

}
```

This is the model

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "product")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column (name = "idProduct")
    private Integer idProduct;

    @Column (name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;

    @Column (name = "descripcion")
    private String descripcion;

    @Column (name = "marca")
    private String marca;

    @Column (name = "precio")
    private float precio;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "producto")
    private Set<OrderLine> orderLines;

    public Product() {

    }

    public Product(String nombre, String descripcion, String marca, float precio) {
        super();
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.marca = marca;
        this.precio = precio;
    }



    public Integer getIdProduct() {
        return idProduct;
    }
    public void setId(Integer idProduct) {
        this.idProduct = idProduct;
    }
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }
    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }
    public String getMarca() {
        return marca;
    }
    public void setMarca(String marca) {
        this.marca = marca;
    }
    public float getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }
    public void setPrecio(float precio) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }   

}
```

This is the form in HTML.

```
<form th:action="@{/addProduct}" th:object="${producto}"
                    method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="nombre" class="control-label">Nombre</label> <input
                            id="nombre" class="form-control" th:field="*{nombre}" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="descripcion" class="control-label">Descripción</label>
                        <input id="descripcion" class="form-control"
                            th:field="*{descripcion}" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="marca" class="control-label">Marca</label> <input
                            id="marca" class="form-control" th:field="*{marca}" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="precio" class="control-label">Precio</label> <input
                            id="precio" class="form-control" th:field="*{precio}" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Añadir
                            producto</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah controller is bad in updateProduct. Instead of:

```
 model.addAttribute("producto", producto);
```

Write:

```
 model.addAttribute("producto1", producto);
```

Because in thymeleaf you referenced it in th:object as producto1 not as producto.

Comment: Thanks for help me to notice the typo. I put producto instead producto1 and edit the post with the changes. But the error doesn't disapear.

Comment: Hmmm, i can only have a blind guess at what went wrong, but you specified th:object as producto in thymeleaf. In your post mapping of addProduct you receive some bad parameters like Model, nombre... What you can receive is Producto producto, and then use productService.addProduct(producto). But please post your Product class and ProductService so I can have a look.

Comment: I added service, service implementation and model.

Comment: Use your second addProduct method with argument Product, you currently dont need the other one and try it out ike this 
    'public String addProduct(Product product)'

Comment: How I do?
 ``` @PostMapping (value = "/addProduct")
 public String addProduct (Product producto) {
  productService.addProduct(producto);
  return "producto";
  
 }
```

Comment: Yeah, that seems about right. Does it still show error? Have you tried console to see if there is more information?

Comment: The same error. I used many spots in a debug but nothing arrive to the model.

Comment: It's resolved. One missing method in MainController was the cause. Thanks for de help.